# Modifying default tool in Okular - Linux

Tags: okular

I am using Okular as my pdf reader on Linux. I want to know how can make highlighter be the default tool. Because after i highlight a sentence it changes to *Browse*.

I have tried to change default options in *settings* but i could not do anything with this problem.

Any help?

**EDIT** i have found a way to overcome that difficulty, download Xournal, it is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By double clicking the Highlighter in Okular. Just tried. It worked